# Android: String value in DateTime field?

Tags: android, sqlite

I've accidentally inserted the string datetime() into my database (in stead of the result of the function), and never saw my mistake until i did a listing of the data. The string "datetime()" is in the date field of all the records, yet the field type is datetime!

Is this normal for the sqllite that is on Android?? What's the point of field types then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sqlite isn't strongly statically typed like most databases. When you assign a type to a column, it's  more like a suggestion about how you'd want the value stored.   If you create a column which is a text column, it will store numbers you put there as strings, since it can convert a number to a string for you.  If you create a column with a integer type and try to store a string in it, it stores a string if it can't be converted to an integer.  Read more about it [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)